# Calculate most recent payment date from multiple rows of payment information in excel

Tags: excel, date, difference

My data are in the following format:

[image]

This information is regarding accounts that have been outsourced to a collection agency. As you can see, we have multiple rows for each agency, and multiple rows for each date in which those accounts were withdrawn and assigned. For example, the first agency, Bob Agency, was assigned on 3/12/15, withdrawn on 6/12/15, and assigned to Carla Agency on 6/30/15. Each agency is shown in a different column, and the first two corresponding columns in "Agency Date" refer to their assignment and withdrawl. If the cells are blank, that means that the accounts have not been withdrawn/assigned respectively.

I want to calculate the difference in days between when the account is assigned to any given agency, and the date of the **most recent** assignment. So using the previous example, the difference between 6/30/15 and 3/12/15.

My problem is that I can't work around the blank dates. Some accounts have multiple assignments and withdrawals, and others have just one.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming column L is empty, place this formula there:

```
=IF(MAX(G2:K2)=0,TODAY()-F2,MAX(G2:K2)-F2)
```

It will calculate the most recent assignment date and subtract it from the initial date. If no re-assignment date is there, it will use today's date.

Comment: What if I wanted to create a new column that tells me what the most recent vendor is? Could I add a formula to a separate column to do that?

Comment: You could @Daniel. If you have a question on how to do that, please post another question on SO, as it is separate from your original question. Also, if this answered worked for your original question, please mark it as answered by clicking the green check mark.

Comment: I see. I can't post more than one question per week. Would you be able to show me the solution anyway?

Comment: @Daniel - I bet you can post another question now. Your rep points just went up!

Comment: No dice, I think I have to still wait

Comment: @Daniel -> Try this formula `=Offset(C1,0,counta(C1:E1)-1)`

Comment: Pay it forward @Daniel :)